# objc object pointing

Tags: objective-c, oop

I'm trying to access an object in an implementation file where the method looks like this:
`- (Boolean)humanIsAlive:(id)humanobj;` However, Xcode complains that no such object exists and the build fails.

In the main file, `main.m`, I would write this in the `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Human *human = [[Human alloc] init];
    MyHuman *myhuman = [[MyHuman alloc] init];

    [human create:@"John Doe" age:25];
    if ([human humanIsAlive:myhuman]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is alive and well.", myhuman.humanName);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ is dead and gone.", myhuman.humanName);
    }

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the code that Xcode complains about:

```
- (Boolean)humanIsAlive:(id)humanobj {
    if (humanobj.living == YES) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

It seems legit and everything but Xcode complains that no such properties exist within this object and no such object exists.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties on objects with type `id` cannot safely be resolved to an instance method on any one object, so they are forbidden by the language.  Besides, if you could add properties to `id` itself, we'd have one screwed up language.

All you need to do is be more specific:

```
- (BOOL) humanIsAlive:(MyHuman*)humanobj { //... }
```

If you absolutely need to handle two disparate types of objects, be a little more safe about it and use `-isKindOfClass:`, then cast the object where appropriate to use it's properties.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is wait for the user to input an object and access the properties from there.

Comment: If you need one method to handle two disparate types of objects (which should never happen design-wise), then declare it to take an object of type `id`, then test for the class of it with `-isKindOfClass:` and cast appropriately.